# Does complementary transistors have shoot throughs?

Tags: push-pull, shoot-through

Here I have 2 push-pull circuits one made from a complementary BJT [CPH5524](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cph5524-d.pdf)  and the other using also a complementary MOSFET [BSL316C](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BSL316C_rev2+3.pdf?fileId=db3a30431add1d95011aed6aee7702ee).

I would like to be able to push and pull at a frequency of about 100 kHz. I worried about shoot through which might cause things to get too hot for comfort. If I choose "complementary" parts does this eliminate the problems of shoot through, thus eliminating the effort needed to look for matching parts?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZBDT4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What are the advantages of using a BJT push-pull rather than a MOSFET push-pull? Both the parts mentioned satisfy my requirements of a 24 V (maximum) 1 A load, switch times are also way above than what is required. Which one is inherently better?

Comment: I'm assuming that with "shoot through" you mean that both transistors are on at the same time so a current flows through both of them. Analyze the circuits, start with the NPN-PNP one. To make the NPN conduct, what needs to happen? This has to do with the NPN's \$V_{BE}\$. Do the same for the PNP. Draw the voltages in the schematic. Can that situation even exist?

Comment: *Which one is inherently better* Both have advantages and disadvantages. To be able to answer which one is "better" you will need to explain what properties are more or less important to you.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I just really want to push and pull a 24V at 100KHz PWM frequency,

Comment: *I just really want to push and pull a 24V at 100KHz PWM frequency* Sure you can just "want that" but then you're also forgetting about many things. Both of these circuits will **NOT** output the full 0 / Vsource. Instead their output voltages will be 5 V - 0.7 V / 0.7 V for the NPN-PNP circuit. The MOSFET version is probably worse still as there the Vt of the MOSFETs the limiting factor. **Neither circuit can do 24 V from the 5 V input.** You want to "design" or "choose" without **understanding how the circuit works and what its limitations are**. That is the way to failure! Don't go that way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Does complimentary transistors have shoot throughs?*

The emitter follower and source follower push-pull configurations shown in your question **DO NOT** have any issues regarding shoot-through.

> *If i choose "complementary" parts does this eliminate the problems of
> shoot through?*

In the circuit configurations shown, there are **NO ISSUES** regarding shoot-through. Complementary parts are not going to be needed. Of course, both parts ought to be NPN and PNP and, rated for equivalent voltage, current and hFE but, there can never be a shoot-through issue with this type of circuit because you **CANNOT** have both transistors biased "on" at the same time due to the way the bases (gates) are connected.

You get potential shoot-through problems when operating a push-pull circuit with the transistors connected as common emitter (common source) but, that isn't the case in your schematics.

> *Both the parts mentioned does satisfy my requirements of a
> 24v(maximum) 1A load*

If your supply voltage is 24 volts and you wish to have a switching output that can produce 24 volts and 0 volts then, (as shown and implied) neither of these circuits can be expected to perform adequately and particularly, the MOSFET circuit will "lose" several volts from the 24 volts rail and similarly when switching towards 0 volts. If you need hard-switching to both supply rails, then both these circuits are ineffective with the MOSFET version being significantly worse than the BJT circuit.

Of course, you can improve the hard-switching capabilities of "follower" push-pull stages but, this will involve significant re-design of the driver circuits to the bases/gates.

Comment: Oh so I can choose cheaper transistors then if thats the case. I did some simulation with 2n3904 and 2n3906 (with a level shifter on the base of the pushpull) and indeed im loosing about 1v on the output, 1v is still okay though. Can you show me a more proper way of doing this?

Comment: If cost is a big factor then no. You get what you pay for. Performance comes with cost as with most things in life.

Comment: This will be a one-off circuit, so im a bit willing to spend a little. What i ment on my last comment is since complementary is not a requirement anymore there is no more need to pay extra. But there still a limit though, Is this a very expensive circuit ? O.O

Comment: I'd consider using an FOD8342 as a quite powerful driver that is optically isolated too. Cost is justified by performance.

Comment: I think its price is fair for what it offers, but i find it a bit overkill. How about this [IC](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/IX4426-27-28.pdf/$file/IX4426-27-28.pdf) your suggestion lead me to gate drivers for mosfets which uses push - pull.

Comment: @Jakequin sure, that part is pretty good. If you need more amps on the output IXYS do even more powerful drivers too. There are a few companies in the business and I'm glad you managed to find this range of gate drivers.

Comment: @Jakequin "1v is still okay though" 1V drop @ 1A = 1W power dissipation or 500 mW at 50% duty cycle. That's pushing it for the 2N3904 / 3906.

Comment: A question though, since the IC are mosfets drivers are they well suited with prolonged loads >? since mosfets typically only need the high current load until the gate is charged, are the IC capable of constant load on the outputs?

Comment: The data sheets will give reasonable hints on what the output voltage drops to under load currents. If that isn't enough information then the data sheets will also specify the effective output resistance of the driver so you can work that out yourself knowing your specific load current @Jakequin